# Video recorded by PrtScrn -> Screencast looks strange. How to fix?

Tags: sound, video, desktop-recording

After pressing on <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> and going to the video mode to record a video of the desktop, the recorded video shows the following issue: [image: screencast video issue]

How do I fix this **Screencast** video mode recording issue? The Screencast is able to take a photo of the Desktop but not able to record video on the Desktop.

> **System details:**
>
> Ubuntu 22.04
>
> Acer E14 laptop.
>
> Linux 6.2.0-35-generic

FYI:

1. The Cheese app also could not work but the Guvcview app does work.
2. The Zoom app works right out of the box.

Comment: Are you on Wayland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the default display server which is Wayland in the Ubuntu `22.04`. In the earlier LTS versions, it was **Xorg**. Most of the recording software or even screen-sharing applications like Google Meet, Zoom, etc. support **Xorg**. Hence they fail because of incompatibility with this comparatively new display server.
You can change this by the following steps:

> Edit the configuration file,
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
> ```
>
> to uncomment [remove # from] the line containing
>
> ```
> WaylandEnable=false
> ```
>
> save the file (<kbd>**ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and after that
> <kbd>y</kbd> ('yes') or another key for non-English and finally
> **Enter**) and **reboot**.